# Accessing objects by attribute Value through DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

We are accessing Doors from an external .Net-program via DXL.

In that program we are currently getting all Objects linked to that Object through their modulname/absolute number from their links.
Now we have to neglect those, because we got an attribute grouping certain objects together (lets call it GroupID) and we need to link through GroupIDs saved in another attribute in our source object.

The actual question is, if theres any way to search objects for their certain attribute values?

I didnt find anything useful in the DXL documentation and the only way I can imagine right now, is iterating over the objects in a module an compare the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you transfer the objects from DXL to .Net, if you use DXL scripts for preparing the objects and sending them, so this might not apply for you:

In DXL, you could use a filter (see chapter 25 "Display Control"→"Filters" in the DXL manual) and then use the "for Object in Module" loop that will traverse all filtered objects. But if I remember correctly, filters are internally implemented using something like a "for Object in entire Module" loop, so you might get the same speed using a manual iteration.

Comment: Will the filter be executed on the Doors client or server? If its on the server it would reduce data sent over the network. Thats atleast something.

Comment: sorry, only on the client. But you could of course use a DOORS client which runs on the same machine as the DOORS Server